# make: *** No rule to make target 'build-x86_64'. Stop

Tags: docker, makefile, operating-system

I am following a tutorial series on yt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkrpUaGThTQ
how to make an os soo
when in **Build for x86 ** use the command `make build-x86_64` then it shows this error `

> make: *** No rule to make target 'build-x86_64'.  Stop.

`
I dont know how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Per the original YouTube author of the tutorial, this is the fix :

> Try one of the following commands when entering the docker container from your host OS

For Linux, MacOS, WSL, etc :

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$pwd":/root/env myos-buildenv
docker run --rm -it -v "$PWD":/root/env myos-buildenv
docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)":/root/env myos-buildenv
```

Windows Powershell :

```
docker run --rm -it -v "${pwd}:/root/env" myos-buildenv
```

Windows CMD :

```
docker run --rm -it -v "%cd%":/root/env myos-buildenv
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to go back one directory by typing
"cd .."
then enter another command
"cd env" to move into the env folder
then you can enter "make build x86_64" command

Answer (score 0):

Make the "MakeFile" file name as "makefile" and run the command "make build-x86_64"

Answer (score 0):

Same problem I had. Just go on with Carey S.Turner`s answer.

Windows Powershell: docker run --rm -it -v "${pwd}:/root/env" myos-buildenv

Windows CMD: docker run --rm -it -v "%cd%":/root/env myos-buildenv

I had error with cmd but powershell worked fine for me.

Comment: Do not copy someone else's answer and post it as your own because it helped you. When you [have enough rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) you can upvote or comment on theirs to confirm that it works.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error I found that it could be fixed by doing this bit right

Enter build environment:

> Linux or MacOS: docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)":/root/env myos-buildenv
> Windows (CMD): docker run --rm -it -v "%cd%":/root/env myos-buildenv
> Windows (PowerShell): docker run --rm -it -v
> "${pwd}:/root/env" myos-buildenv
> Please use the linux command if you are using WSL, msys2 or git bash NOTE: If you are having trouble with an unshared drive, ensure your docker daemon has access to the drive you're development environment is in. For Docker Desktop, this is in "Settings > Shared Drives" or "Settings > Resources > File Sharing".

(https://github.com/davidcallanan/os-series/blob/ep1/README.md)

My error came out of me not doing the "$(pwd)" bit correctly

Comment: -1 as `pwd` as root cause was already mentioned in other answers. See [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)